# How to check whether an error happened on a specific property with spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, taglib

I'm using the form tag.

```
<form:form commandName="foo">
    <div class="myclass  ">
        <label>Foo</label>
            <form:input path="fooName"/>
    </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit"/>
        </div>
</form:form>
```

**Question**

Is there a way to find out if an error happened on a specific field?

I am aware of the `<form:erros path="fooName"/>` but this will print out the error message. I am after something that simply returns true or false based on if the error happened on `fooName` property. I need this because if the error happened then I can insert the css class `error` next to `my class`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>                             
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>

<form:form commandName="foo">
    <spring:bind path="fooName">
        <div class="myclass ${status.error ? 'error' : ''}">
            <label>Foo</label>
            <form:input path="fooName"/>
        </div>
    </spring:bind>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit"/>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

When you enclose field inside [`<spring:bind>`](http://static.springsource.org/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/BindTag.html) tag you have access to implicit variable `status` of type [`BindStatus`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/BindStatus.html). You may use it to check that field has error or not.

You also probaly find useful following links:

- [Spring MVC and Twitter Bootstrap – customizing the input fields](http://duckranger.com/2012/07/spring-mvc-and-twitter-bootstrap-customizing-the-input-fields/)
- [Spring MVC + Bootstrap Errors (extended)](http://monocaffe.blogspot.in/2012/12/spring-mvc-bootstrap-errors-extended.html)

---

Here is another way with [`<spring:hasBindErrors>`](http://static.springsource.org/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/BindErrorsTag.html) (inside it you have access to `errors` variable of type [`Errors`](http://static.springsource.org/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html)) which will work only in environment with **JSP 2.2**:

```
<spring:hasBindErrors name="foo">
    <div class="myclass ${errors.hasFieldErrors('fooName') ? 'error' : ''}">
        <label>Foo</label>
        <form:input path="fooName"/>
    </div>
</spring:hasBindErrors>
```

Comment: by useing `hasBindErrors` combined with `hasFieldErrors` I get this error - `The function hasFieldErrors must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified`

Comment: As I just found, `errors.hasFieldErrors()` expression only works in JSP 2.2 environment. So, it depends from servlet container/application server which your use. See the following thread: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?72031-JSP-error-must-be-used-with-a-prefix-when-a-default-namespace-is-not-specified